# Merge 2 JS scripts - old school

Tags: javascript, html-table

I can't figure it out to merge 2 small and simple JS scripts to one script on one page. It's a MouseOver table select script to change the color of the cell. Old school, I know, but sometimes very handy for something. But now, I can't figure it out to merge it on the right way. I can't find it on the internet. A test page is setup here: http://www.efens.nl/demo/000javascripttest.htm See the source code.

What did I miss?

```js
function selectlink(currentmenu,linkmenu){
    currentmenu.style.background='yellow';

    if (document.getElementById)
      document.getElementById("selectmenu").innerHTML=linkmenu;
    else
      selectmenu.innerHTML=html;
}
function leavelink(currentmenu){
    currentmenu.style.background='blue';

    if (document.getElementById)
      document.getElementById("selectmenu").innerHTML='&nbsp;';
    else
      selectmenu.innerHTML='&nbsp;';
}



function selectlink(currentblok,linkblok){
    currentblok.style.background='blue';

    if (document.getElementById)
      document.getElementById("selectblok").innerHTML=linkblok;
    else
      selectblok.innerHTML=html;
}
function leavelink(currentblok){
    currentblok.style.background='yellow';

    if (document.getElementById)
      document.getElementById("selectblok").innerHTML='&nbsp;';
    else
      selectblok.innerHTML='&nbsp;';
}
```

```css
td.menu {font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:bold;
        background-color:blue;
        cursor:hand
}
td.blok {font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:bold;
        background-color:yellow;
        cursor:hand
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<table width=200>
<tr>
    <td class="menu" 
        bordercolor="black"
        id="choice1"
        onmouseover="selectMenu(this,'AAA')"
        onmouseout="leavelink(this)">

           <a href="http://www.java2s.com">AAA</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="menu" 
        bordercolor="black"
        id="choice2"
        onmouseover="selectMenu(this,'BBB')"
        onmouseout="leavelink(this)">

           <a href="http://www.java2s.com">BBB</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="menu"  
        bordercolor="black"
        id="choice3"
        onmouseover="selectMenu(this,'CCC')"
        onmouseout="leavelink(this)">

           <a href="http://www.java2s.org/">CCC</a>
    </td>
</tr>
    <td class="menu" 
        bordercolor="black"
        id="choice4"
        onmouseover="selectMenu(this,'DDD')"
        onmouseout="leavelink(this)">

           <a href="http://www.java2s.com">DDD</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bordercolor="black" bgcolor="white" height="18">
      <font id="selectMenu" size="2"></font>
    </td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<p><font size="2">MouseOver:&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;Blue to Yellow (return to Blue)</font></p>
<p>===================================================================</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="blok">
<table width=200 id="table2">
<tr>
    <td class="blok" bordercolor="black"
        id="choice5"
        onmouseover="selectlink(this,'AAA')"
        onmouseout="leavelink(this)">

           <a href="http://www.java2s.com">AAA</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="blok" bordercolor="black"
        id="choice6"
        onmouseover="selectlink(this,'BBB')"
        onmouseout="leavelink(this)">

           <a href="http://www.java2s.com">BBB</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="blok" bordercolor="black"
        id="choice7"
        onmouseover="selectlink(this,'CCC')"
        onmouseout="leavelink(this)">

           <a href="http://www.java2s.org/">CCC</a>
    </td>
</tr>
    <td class="blok" bordercolor="black"
        id="choice8"
        onmouseover="selectlink(this,'DDD')"
        onmouseout="leavelink(this)">

           <a href="http://www.java2s.com">DDD</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bordercolor="black" bgcolor="white" height="18">
      <font id="selectdesc0" size="2"></font>
    </td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<p><font size="2">MouseOver:&nbsp; Yellow to Blue (return to Yellow)</font></p>
```

Comment: You want return to blue?

Comment: correct, Mouseover: 
first table from yellow to blue (and back to yellow)
second tabele from blue to yelloe (and back to blue) opposite
The script conflict in the first table, mouseover.

Comment: Why are you not doing it simply. check out my answer for two different links.

Comment: Why did i think so difficult. This is indead very simple. Better than old school JS.  Byby JS and welcome CSS.
Thx case closed : )

Comment: Just accept answer it it is helpful to keep people answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using `hover` selector of css.

Example:

```
<a href="#" class="yellowtoblue">Yellow To Blue</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" class="bluetoyellow">Blue To Yellow</a>
```

CSS:

```
.yellowtoblue{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;

    background-color:yellow;
}
.yellowtoblue:hover{
     background-color:blue;

}

.bluetoyellow{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;

    background-color:blue;
}
.bluetoyellow:hover{
     background-color:yellow;

}
```

[Check Out Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pycv0jem/1/)